# Why is this C program NOT causing a segmentation fault with alphanumeric values?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, internal

In its simplest form the program is

```
int main(){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",x);
}
```

When we give this program any numeric value as input it fails by producing a segfault signal which is what we should expect.

But if we instead give it any alphanumeric value it *does not* fail.

What is going on in the `scanf` that produces this behavior?

This is the backtrace from gdb when running it with a numeric value:

```
(gdb) bt

 #0  0x00000034e7456ed0 in _IO_vfscanf_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6

 #1  0x00000034e74646cd in __isoc99_scanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6

 #2  0x0000000000400553 in main ()
```

So why is it *not* failing for any alphanumeric value like 'a' or 'dfgb'?

Comment: You are trying to reason about *undefined behavior* here. In this specific case it could be that `scanf` is not even trying to access the second argument, as the input is not matching the format string. But I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: "If a character in the input stream conflicts with format-string, the function ends, terminating with a 'matching' failure. The conflicting character is left in the input stream as if it had not been read." Your alphabetic inputs fail to match the expected decimal format, so `scanf()` exits without trying to write anything to your faulty "address".

Comment: Disagree with "When we give this program any numeric value as input it fails by producing a segfault signal which is what we should expect.".  With this code, providing number input leads to undefined behavior, not necessarily seg fault.  Seg is one possible expectation, but not the only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 7.21.6.2/10 of the standard say:

> If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the
>   directive fails: this condition is a matching failure.

and 7.21.6.2/4:

> The fscanf function executes each directive of the format in turn.
>   When all directives have been executed, or if a directive fails (as
>   detailed below), the function returns. Failures are described as input
>   failures (due to the occurrence of an encoding error or the
>   unavailability of input characters), or matching failures (due to
>   inappropriate input).

As your input provides no good parsable integer, `scanf` just returns 0 to signal that no conversion was made from input and do not try to dereference the argument you passed.

*This answer was edited to cite the standard about that point, thank to @Zwol*.

Comment: I don't think this _is_ undefined behavior.  [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.21.6.2 is the specification of (f)scanf.  The behavior of conversion directives is described as a step-by-step algorithm, and it appears to me that the implementation is required **not** to access the "object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument  that  has  not  already  received  a  conversion  result" unless conversion succeeds.  Since this is a variadic function, nothing else enforces the requirement for each variable argument to be a pointer.

Comment: @zwol That's right, 7.21.6.2 /10 is clear about it, need editing, thanks.